# Kubernetes job is unable to connect to cloud sql(mysql) in gcp

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am creating a kubernetes job from pod with help of kubernetes python package in GCP. While creating job I am passing all the environment variables of pod into job. Pod can connect to mysql server with same db configuration but job is not able to make a connection with mysql.The created job is in the same cluster as pod. The Pod is able to connect to the cloud sql in gcp on 127.0.0.1 but the job is not able to connect to mysql on 127.0.0.1.

Getting this error: OperationalError: (2006, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (115)")

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is your loopback address. From your job pod perspective, it would suggest that your SQL database is running as a sidecar. Which is probably not the case. You should figure out: what's your database IP address, and where to set that as a param starting your job

Comment: My other pods are connecting without any issues to mysql on 127.0.0.1:3306 . Only the Job pod that is created dynamically is not able to connect to the Mysql

Comment: I'm not sure how that's supposed to work. By design, a pod implements network isolation, it is expected its loopback would be unique to your pod. I would investigate your other pods, is there anything listening on that loopback. A sidecar, maybe. Makes no sense otherwise. Try to understand what loopback addresses are ... there is no reason 127.0.0.1 would route anywhere else but your pod itself.